# Read Table, block and tuple

Tags: tuples, block, monetdb

I have inserted into the `orders` table from TPCH using MonetDB.

Now I'd like to read it programmatically.

How can I read a table, block and tuple on `monetDB`?

Is there any way to read an specific block from a table?

Comment: I'm a master degree student and I have to write some codes at the source.
Actually, What I'm trying to do is:
Read a table, block and tuple at the source code and put this on a specific space of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a "block" is in this context, but MonetDB can be accessed programmatically from a variety of programming languages including C/C++, Python, R and Java.

For more details, see the [Language Bindings](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Programming) page on the MonetDB developers website.

Which programming language are you using?